# InfoPath handling via browser but without Sharepoint or Office Forms Sever

Tags: .net, sharepoint, infopath

I have searched half of the internet in order to find a solution to render, fill out and save  InfoPath form via web browser (IE only scenario is also good in my case). But I have found nothing.

I have already tried exporting InfoPath form to Web Page from InfoPath itself - but of course such form is just static and read only html .

1. Do you know any InfoPath rendering engine or framework (best if .NET) that would allow me to let customers fill out InfoPath forms but without me having SharePoint or Office Forms server?
2. Do you know any alternative to InfoPath that would allow defining form template (via browser or desktop app) and then filling those forms via web browser (also best if .NET)?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, SharePoint Foundation is a free alternative to SharePoint enterprise.

For your second question, you can use.aspx pages instead of InfoPath forms in SharePoint. These are compatible with workflows and use templates and master pages.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer. However according to wiki Infopath forms can be handeled only by Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint#Microsoft_SharePoint_Foundation  And about second part i was thinking about some framework that would spare me writing all the code. Is there any?